# data-clipboard-text is not working while using clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I have a simple structure to test `clipboard.js` but it's not working.

I used in a simple file because it was not working in the project too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should — clipboard.js">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give some more context please so we can help you. Are there any errors in the console? Anyhting that can lead to solving this problem?

Comment: @Clara No errors on the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you need to instantiate it by passing a DOM selector, HTML element, or
>   list of HTML elements.

```
new ClipboardJS('.btn');
```

https://clipboardjs.com/#setup

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should — clipboard.js">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    new ClipboardJS('.btn');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```